# Initializing an Anaconda-Project fails if .git is present

Tags: python, windows, git, anaconda, conda

I decided to try out the relatively new Anaconda-Project functionality of Anaconda. Did a fresh install of the latest version of Anaconda (v5.0.1) on my Windows 7 machine and started following this guide:
http://anaconda-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html

I created a new directory and created a Git repository for it, then opened Anaconda Prompt, navigated to the directory and typed `anaconda-project init` which resulted in this error message:

`Failed to run 'git ls-files'; [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Unable to load the project.`

If I navigate to an empty directory with no .git folder and run the same command, the anaconda-project.yml file is created as expected and I don't get the error.

Any idea why trying to initialize an anaconda-project in a git repo doesn't work? In case it is important, I typically create my Git repository on Github or BitBucket and then clone it locally using GitKraken.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `git` added to your windows PATH, this is a setting during the installation that defaults to have it added

Comment: No Git is not on my PATH - and Git was installed by GitKraken (a graphical git client) which doesn't seem to have that option at install.
edit: Although actually GitKraken may be using an existing Git install rather than installing it itself.